# unable to update the output

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to write a code to play hangman and it is working correctly but every time when I input a character, it resets my output. Can someone please help.

my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class game
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String list[] = {"apple", "banana", "mango", "kiwi", "coconut", "papaya", "lichi", "strawberry", "orange", "cherry"};
        int rand = (int)(Math.random()*9)+0;
        String word = list[rand];
        String ask = "_";
        for(int i = 1; i < word.length();i++){
            ask = ask + "_";
        }
        System.out.println(ask);
        System.out.println("hint: It is a fruit");
        for (int j = 1; j<=15; j++){
            System.out.println("Enter a character: ");
            char input = in.next().charAt(0);
            for (char i : word.toCharArray()){
                if(input == i){
                    System.out.print(input);
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.print("_");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A small piece of the output:

```
______
hint: It is a fruit

Enter a character: 
a
__a___
Enter a character: 
o
o_____
Enter a character: 
r
_r____
Enter a character: 
n
___n__
Enter a character:
```

When I enter 'a' it prints it correctly but when I enter some other character it prints that character an not 'a'. Can somebody pls tell me what should I do to get the correct output.

Comment: Well then...it's not working correctly after all. You already have the variable ask which basically contains the required letter placements. All you need to do is overwrite the positions where the inputted character actually exist. You can do it using something like this: `ask = ask.substring(0, i) + input + ask.substring(i + 1);` but then of course you will need to iterate through the random word and have `i` hold the current index being checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not saving the string with the character added to the game, you are only printing it. You will probably want to do something like add the new character to the string variable _ask rather than printing as you go, then print after the for loop has run. Basically you are not storing the past rounds anywhere.

Comment: thank you for helping me and telling me how should I solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

I think that,
In the loop `for (char i : word.toCharArray())`,

you should add the character to `ask` (*or have another string variable named `ans`*),

and then print `ask` at the end of the loop

---

because you are not updating the value of ask and printing the place of the character in the string,
and when the loop runs a second time it doesn't show the last character that u entered

> plus you can have specific hints according to the fruit name using switch case

> and maybe have an error pop up when the player enters the wrong character

Comment: I am unable to understand your answer. thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer you need to remember the characters from previous attempts. This could for example be done like this:

```
String tempAsk = "";
for (char i : word.toCharArray()){
  if(input == i){
    tempAsk += i;
  } else {
    tempAsk += ask.charAt(i);
  }
}
ask = tempAsk;
System.out.println(ask);
```

Comment: I guess it is not the answer I was looking for. Still thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a character array to check what letters are present so far like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String list[] = {"apple", "banana", "mango", "kiwi", "coconut", "papaya", "lichi", "strawberry", "orange", "cherry"};
    int rand = (int)(Math.random()*9)+0;
    String word = list[rand];

    // Create a character array to store the result so far
    char[] result = new char[word.length()];

    //Fill the array with _
    Arrays.fill(result, '_');

    System.out.println(new String(result));

    System.out.println("hint: It is a fruit");
    int numChances = 15;
    for (int j = 1; j <= numChances; j++){
        System.out.println("Enter a character: ");
        char input = in.next().charAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if(word.charAt(i) == input){
                //update the array with user's correct response
                result[i] = input;
            }
        }

        // Check how we're doing so far. Make a string with the result
        String untilNow = new String(result);

        // Show user what we have so far
        System.out.println(untilNow);
        
        //Check if the user has guessed the word. 
        if(untilNow.equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
            System.out.println("You win...");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just started java and I do not know some of the methods which you have used

Comment: I have retained your code. I have an additional character array to track player's progress so far. The array contains the correct characters guessed by the player so far. Think of it as the fill-in-the-blanks array that contains the correctly guessed character in their position, and _ elsewhere. `char[] result = new char[word.length()];` creates the array, and `Arrays.fill(result, '_');` fills them with blanks initially.